# Trigger with cursor shown error : Trigger is invalid and failed re-validation

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers, oracle10g, database-trigger

I'm trying to create Oracle after insert trigger with the following code:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AutoManhour
  AFTER INSERT ON TBL_MSTPROJECT
   FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
  CURSOR c_Section IS
    SELECT IDSECTION AS IDSECTION FROM TBL_MSTSECTIONHR;
    v_Section c_Section%ROWTYPE;
  BEGIN
    OPEN c_Section;
    LOOP
        FETCH c_Section INTO v_Section;
       INSERT INTO TBL_TRXMANHOURS (ID_SECTION,INPUTBY_TRXMANHOURS,INPUTON_TRXMANHOURS,ID_PROJECT)
        VALUES (v_Section.IDSECTION,'IT_ROBOT',SYSDATE,:new.IDPROJECT);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c_Section;
END AutoManhour;
/
```

But it retrieve an error :

> ORA-04098: trigger 'DEPEEL.AUTOMANHOUR' is invalid and failed
>   re-validation

Why does this happen?

Comment: For me its not throwing any error from this trigger, can you share the minimum DDL for tables those are present in trigger

Comment: the error says : PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
   ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge

Comment: It doesn't appear to have anything to do with the error you're getting but what you've presented here is an infinite loop.  You'd need an exit condition.  Or simplify the code dramatically with an implicit cursor loop rather than an explicit cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have used the incorrect column/table names or incorrect datatypes are used while inserting data into `TBL_TRXMANHOURS`. And of course, there is an infinite loop, You should make some condition to make it finite

Oracle will try to recompile invalid objects as they are referred to. Here the trigger is invalid

```
select * from user_errors where type = 'TRIGGER' and name = 'AUTOMANHOUR'
```

You can try the above query to find the actual error.

Cheers!!